# How many sub-trees a binary tree has?

Tags: binary-tree, subtree

Given a binary tree with n nodes. We can use in-order to represent the tree as an array of nodes. Would it be a fair assumption to say that I can represent any sub-tree by choosing 2 nodes from the in-order array? So that the total number of sub-trees is (n choose 2) which is O(n^2) or is the total number of sub-trees is O(2^n)?

Edit: I don't need to find the exact number, but know the approximate number.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by choosing 2 nodes from the array? This statement is a bit confusing.

Comment: What I mean is that by choosing two nodes, I define the most left node and the most right node of the sub-tree, like the borders.

Comment: By that definition, You are correct in your n choose 2 logic. However, this is not the typical definition of a subtree. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Subtree